# Detectar click en modal form

Tags: jquery

Tengo este codigo para listar articulos dentro de un modal:

```html
function listar(){

    tipofiltro="todos";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                         "<td>"+"<input type='text' class='form-control input-sm-2' id='cant' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' name='agregar' id='"+data.idproducto+"'  >+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }
        
  

        }  
});
};
```

Y como veran tiene un elemento "a" con el mismo name y el idproducto, la idea es añadir a la cesta, pero no logro detectar el cliock.
Lo que hice fue:

```html
  $("a[name=agregar]").click(function(){

   
      alert('hh');   

    });
```

Selecciono por nombre, luego quisiera obtener el id del elemento que es el id del producto.
Codigo completo del js:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();

$("a[name=agregar]").on('click',function(){


  alert('hh');   

});


var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
    });
   $("#cod").keyup(function() {
       
        codBusqueda=$("#cod").val();
        filtrarcod(codBusqueda);
    });
  var id;
  var nombre;
  var marca;
  var producto;
    var precio;


$("#Agregar").click(function(event){
  var cantidad=$("#cant").val();
  
  if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: {accion,id,cantidad,nombre,marca,precio}, 
  dataType:'html',
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
             alert('agre');      
                      
            }
        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});

    
  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }
});



function filtrarcod(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
 if (content[i].codalfa.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
            $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                          "<td>"+"<input type='text'class='form-control input-sm' id='cant'tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' name='agregar' id='"+filtrado.idproducto+"'>+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }
 
  
}};
function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+"<input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' id='cant'tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' name='agregar' id='"+filtrado.idproducto+"' >+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
function listar(){

    tipofiltro="todos";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                         "<td>"+"<input type='text' class='form-control input-sm-2' id='cant' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' name='agregar' id='"+data.idproducto+"'  >+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }
        
  

        }  
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero en tu javascript agregar el evento *onclick* mediante el cual llames a una funcion agregarProducto dicha función recibe como parametro tu id algo asi:

```
  " <a  class='btn btn-primary' name='agregar' onclick='agregarProducto("+data.idproducto+");'  >+</a></td>"+
  .....
 ......
    function agregarProducto(idproducto){
       alert(idproducto);
      ...
       ....
    }//end function agregarProducto
```

tambien te sugiero verificar que si esta recibiendo el id el evento, digo esto porque tu estas colocando algo asi:

```
data.idproducto
```

pero si lo haces mediante el ciclo for deberia ser asi:

```
data[i]['idproducto']
```

con todo deberias comprobar como traes el id del producto.

suerte y espero te sirva ..!!

Comment: sI, Como veras los datos y el boton se crean al cargar el modal y funciono lo que me dijiste, y faltaba el subindice.

Comment: Y en cada fila tengo el input de cantidad y luego el agregar, como detecto el input correspondiente a la fila del mas clickaedo?

Comment: Probe con id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' en el input y luego: cantidad=$("input[id="+idproducto+"]").val(); pero la segunda vez que lo agrego toma el idproducto como cantidad, porque sera

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de crear un evento `onclik` y dependiendo lo que necesites puedes usar unas u otras.

En tu caso has optado por utilizar el `.click()`. Esto quiere decir que el elemento al que le añades el evento ya existe antes de que se lea el evento.

Otra posibilidad es utilizar `.on('click', function())`. Este evento hace referencia a todos los elemento que coincidan con lo que buscas sin importar si se han creado antes o después.

Por lo que la solución es verificar que el evento se crea después de crear el elemento o sino utilizar el siguiente evento:

```
$("a[name=agregar]").on('click',function(){


  alert('hh');   

});
```

Comment: no funciona aun, entiendo lo que decis. Ahi cooque el js completo.

Comment: No te da ningún error en consola?

Comment: No me marcaba ningun error,pero quizas porque faltaba el subindice no funcionaba.